# Fetching subdocuments with angular $http

Tags: angularjs, recursion, promise, chaining, subdocument

Say you have nested collections `a`, `b`, and `c`, which follow the following map:

```
{"collection":"a",
 "children":[{"collection":"b",
              "name":"bee",
              "children"[{"collection":"c","name":"cee"}]}]}
```

And here is `a1`, fetched from a MongoDb database with `$http`:

```
{"title":"title a1",
 "id":"a1",
 "bee":[{"id":"b1"},{"id":"b2"}],
 "other_array":[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]}
```

Right now, in the `bee` array, we have only references (`id`). What we want is to keep following the map to update `a1`, and replace references by actual data.

It would entail fetching `b1` and `b2` data from database, which could each have `cee` arrays, whose elements we would need to fetch from the `c` collection.

I suppose one could easily create a dedicated backend function, that would take in `a1`, do all the fetching at once and return the end result;

**but how would you get the fully detailed version of `a1` by using multiple $http/$resource calls?**

Should a recursive function be used?

Or would it be best to use $q and chained promises?

How to walk the map (to know which collections are relevant, and what their name is), retrieve the relevant `b` items, then the relevant `c` items, and at the very end update `a1`, so as to replace `a1` with something like:

```
{"title":"title a1","id":"a1","bee":[{"id":"b1","title":"title b1","other_stuff":"blah blah","cee":[{"id":"c1","title":"title c1","c_specific":"hi there"}]},{"id":"b2","title":"title b2","other_stuff":null,"cee":[]}],"other_array":[{"foo":"bar"},{"foo":"baz"}]}
```

Comment: First thing first: __don't do this__, making multiple http calls to fetch a single value you need will slow down your website's response time and provide a bad user experience - I strongly suggest you don't solve it on the client side.

Comment: That said, you can solve this quite easily with promises and recursion - I don't think you'll get reasonable performance but it's certainly possible. How do you function calls look?

Comment: OK, thanks, so do you suggest I build a dedicated function in the backend, which will do the database calls for an 'a' document and all its descendants, and return the document to angular?

Comment: Yes. Or better yet - just store the relevant bits in a single entity in Mongo.

Comment: Right, thanks for the advice, Benjamin. As I am new to StackOverflow, I am not sure what to do: if you answered the question, I could validate it; if you don't want to bother, I could answer it, thereby closing the subject. What do you suggest I do?

Comment: You're actually doing well here - I'm the one misbehaving :P Usually posting answers in comments is bad - you can wait for a day or two you might get a real answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by [benjamin Gruenbaum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1348195/benjamin-gruenbaum),

> making multiple http calls to fetch a single value you need will slow down your website's response time and provide a bad user experience

So I have dropped the idea altogether, and will just fetch one document from the database, which already contains all the nested arrays.

The only downside I see is that, when a subdocument is modified directly, all documents containing the subdocument will have to be manually modified.